# python virtual environment is installing to /usr/...?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a python virtual env that I am using for a django application. I activate it with...

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

that works, but then I get this traceback when trying to run a pip install...

```
Installing collected packages: django-blog-zinnia
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/jeff/.pip/pip.log
```

So why would it be trying to install something in /usr when I am supposed to be running in the venv?

added the output of 
    virtualenv venv

```
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

and when I use source to start that venv and run which python I get this...

```
/home/user/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python
```

Comment: check `which pip`, probably no pip is installed in venv

Comment: it says.../usr/bin/pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of `which pip`, most likly pip is not installed. If it is not pip from venv also check `which python`. If it is not venv's python, your are not in the new env - there should be some errors.

If only pip is missing try to install with:

```
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

edit

Virualenv is only for current shell session. To use in another session/terminal/window you must activate it again. It persists until you `deactivate` it.

Comment: which python also showed /usr/bin...How would I go about fixing that as well?

Comment: show the output of creating virtual env `virtualenv venv`

Comment: I added it to the main post, what should I do now?

Comment: looks ok, so you have right python, check again pip and if needed install it

Comment: one thing...I did this as a new venv, should I be doing it to the same directory where my old one is? I was doing this as a little test

Comment: meaning I created a new venv this time just to see what happened

Comment: i don;t get it? You have created new venv - that is working, try to install django